# Ansible: print pretty xml with Ansible debug module for the xml page saved using register

Tags: python, xml, ansible, uri

How can I print xml saved using register with debug with pretty xml format

```
- name: Create a JIRA issue
  uri:
    url: https://your.jira.example.com/rest/api/2/issue/
    method: GET
    user: your_username
    password: your_pass
    body: "{{ lookup('file','issue.json') }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 201
    body_format: json
    register: test
- debug: {{ test.content }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `test.content` contains only xml you can print the data with the `xml` [module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html)

```
  - xml:
      xmlstring: {{ test.content }}
      pretty_print : yes
```